# How to manipulate data as a pivot_longer data format related to statisticss for plotting data on x and y axis with ggplot

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot

I have the following set of data, got after t-test comparisons

```
structure(list(Comparisons = c("long", "medium", "short"), typology = c("tool", 
"tool", "tool"), estimate = c(11.7479197678953, 12.661186979276, 
11.0395774860837), estimate1 = c(20.8653857387526, 20.7443760097759, 
19.4568444611505), estimate2 = c(24.1174659708573, 23.0831890304999, 
23.4172669750669), .y. = c("value", "value", "value"), group1 = c("group1", 
"group1", "group1"), group2 = c("group2", "group2", "group2"), 
    n1 = c(41, 37, 36), n2 = c(34, 33, 30), statistic = c(t = 12.7479461500939, 
    t = 13.4935246046394, t = 12.0288324427368), p = c(15.0297, 
    15.142, 15.00675), df = c(df = 56.0833418714093, df = 44.914883963806, 
    df = 38.4603356975249), conf.low = c(8.83177960808309, 9.4901671347972, 
    8.28514784157543), conf.high = c(14.6640599277075, 15.8322068237548, 
    13.7940071305919), method = c("T-test", "T-test", "T-test"
    ), alternative = c("two.sided", "two.sided", "two.sided"), 
    lab = c("-2.25  ( t: 0.03 [ -6.17 ; -0.34 ] )  - ", "-1.51  ( t: 0.142 [ -5.51 ; 0.83 ] )  - ", 
    "-2.97  ( t: 0.007 [ -6.71 ; -1.21 ] )  - "), lb = c("RP vs RT: p=-2.25  ( t: 0.03 [ -6.17 ; -0.34 ] )  - ", 
    "RP vs RT: p=-1.51  ( t: 0.142 [ -5.51 ; 0.83 ] )  - ", "RP vs RT: p=-2.97  ( t: 0.007 [ -6.71 ; -1.21 ] )  - "
    ), y.position = c(21.11592, 17.46592, 19.85592), groups = list(
        V1 = c("RP", "RT"), V1 = c("RP", "RT"), V1 = c("RP", 
        "RT")), x = c(1, 2, 3), xmin = c(0.8, 1.8, 2.8), xmax = c(1.2, 
    2.2, 3.2)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Since I would plot with `ggoplot`on `x-axis` the two estimates columns and on the `y axis` those related on two groups I would like to commutate the present dataset in a way to make a pivot long formate but without to change deeply the data structure.

Could please suggest how, considering the purpose of plotting this data? Is there something else that I am ignoring?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why you're not just plotting it `barplot(as.matrix(df[3:5]), beside=TRUE, col=2:4)`.

Comment: In ggplot - the function I am using to get the get the graphs sibce I have to add some details-  I have to specify x and y argument andnit would be nice to to get them as a sngle column.

Comment: I have checked  your code and actually that is not what I am looking for